# Arrays of sentences with toast

Tags: java, android

I am studying Java and Android development, and I want to make this application to understand how it works.

I am using the Toast class so that clicking on the image, to appear a phrase, I could make it work with numbers, but instead of numbers want to put a few sentences and when I click on the image, the phrase appears for a few seconds on the screen.

How to do it without many changes to this code that already have?

```
package android.tutorial.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

// public void mostrarMensagem(View view) {
    //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.sorteia(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    //toast.show();

  //}


 public void mostrarMensagem(View view) {
     int[] lista = new int[]
             {
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
             };
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     for(int i : lista)
     {
          builder.append("" + i + " ");
     }
     Toast.makeText(this, builder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


      }


}
```

Comment: just exchange the numbers against strings with the phrases

Comment: What do you mean? Where is your images and/or phrases?

Comment: @Koogle How ficarai the asintaxe to exchange numbers for phrases?   int [] list = new int []
              {
                 "one phrase "
                 "phrase two"
              };

Comment: @codeMagic The sentences would be here:

int [] list = new int []
              {
                 "one phrase "
                 "phrase two"
              };

I do not have enough reputation to post a screen shot, but it is only a single image on the screen, which sortearia phrases whenever the user to touch the screen.

Comment: I would implement an array with `String phrases [] = { "phrase 1", "phrase 2" ... }` and then use the numbers as indexes: `builder.append("" + phrases[i-1] + " ");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you click on your image,it call 
`public void mostrarMensagem(View view)`
(thanks to onclick in the xml)
Just change change your stingBuilder loop by a String

You can use the same idea and use an array of String, with a increment to change the sentence each time you click.

Edit :

```
String[] sentences = new String[]{"Sentence 1", "Sentence 2", "Sentence 3", "Sentence 4", "Sentence 5"};
int clickCount = 0;
public void mostrarMensagem(View view) {
     Toast.makeText(this, sentences[clickCount], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     clickCount = ++clickCount % sentences.length();
}
```

This should work (can tried with my tablet)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**EDIT**

```
private String [] arr = new String []{"sentence one", "sentence two"};
private int count = 0;

public void mostrarMensagem(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, arr[count%arr.length], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    count++;
}
```

Comment: It even works, but he calls all sentences one after the other with a single click of usario.
I click the user, a message appears, then click it again to appear another message.
The way this, messages are appearing one by one with a single click.

Comment: You need to explain clearly what you want. Do you want to toast a text when a user clicks on the view?

Comment: What I want is that each click appears a different message!

Comment: Then you can do two things.

1. Generate random text and toast it when user clicks on the view.
2. Toast the text that the user gives as an input (in edittext for example)

Comment: I want to do this Generate random text and toast it when user clicks on the view.

Comment: See my edited answer.

this is one way. you have to come up with your own text generator. it depends on you what kind of text do you want to toast. fill in the array with many texts and play around with the array index to make it random ;)